# Automatically create strings as information is entered

Tags: c#, regex, database, string, split

I'm currently trying to get information from an Access database using `OleDb`.
I have a row containing date, time, etc. (logs) of the user and I am retrieving them using:

```c#
connection.Open();
oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, connection);

DataSet dsSet = new DataSet();
oledbAdapter.Fill(dsSet);
foreach (DataRow row in dsSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    rawList.Add(row["Running"].ToString());
}

var show = String.Join(null, rawList.ToArray());
```

I have the following text in my database:

```
|| 04-05-2015 | 7:10 | 2 | 5 mph
|| 04-05-2015 | 12:10 | 1 | 8 mph
```

I separated the 2 sessions using `Regex`:

```c#
var doubleVBarSplit = Regex.Split(show, " \\|\\| ");
```

And used the same sort of thing to separate the data in one session. But the thing I can't figure out is how to separate more sessions from each other and put the the date, time, duration, speed into separate strings so I can display them.

Could anyone guide me on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Split returns an array of strings (string[]), so all you need to do for each session is assign each date, time... for correct index of the string array.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new class and then assign the values from each row of your database to the new class.  I would then add each row to a List of that class.  You can then show this class as you liked.  Also, you said "sessions" but I believe you meant "records".   Code below

```
public class Result
    {
        public Result()
        { }

        public string aDate { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Marker { get; set; }
        public string speed { get; set; }
    }
```

...

```
char pipe = Convert.ToChar("|");
        string[] splits = null;
        List<Result> ResultList = new List<Result>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dsSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            result = new Result();

            splits = String.Format("{0}",row["Running"]).Split(pipe);

            result.aDate = String.Format("{0}", splits[2]);
            result.Time = String.Format("{0}", splits[3]);
            result.Marker = String.Format("{0}", splits[4]);
            result.speed = String.Format("{0}", splits[5]);
            ResultList.Add(result);

        }
```

You can then easily display them as follows:

```
foreach(Result aresult in ResultList) {
String.Format("{0}", aresult.aDate);
aresult.Time;
String.Format("{0}", aresult.Marker);
aresult.Speed;
}
```

Comment: `splits = row.Split(pipe);` is returning `Cannot return symbol 'Split'`.

Comment: Good catch -- I mocked the database and didn't change all my mockups before posting.  Changed it to row["Running"] to match the original post.  In fact, you may have to change  row["Running"] to  row["Running"].ToString() in order to get it to work.

Comment: Edited my answer one final time to ensure that the row value returned is a string and would split correctly.  Should work with the database now.

Comment: Also why did you write `splits[2]` in `result.aDate = Convert.ToDateTime(splits[2]);`? Why not `splits[0]` and then so on for the others?

Comment: I assumed the value of each row was like "|| 04-05-2015 | 7:10 | 2 | 5 mph".  I used a pipe ("|") as my split, so the string created an array each time it saw the pipe.  There are 5 pipes in the example, so the split array created would be "", "", 04-05-2015, 7:10, 2, 5.  So splits[0] and splits[1] would be blank.  splits[2] has 04-05-2015, splits[3] has 7:10 and so on.  The splits are dependent upon the data -- I just assumed the example.  If your data isn't constant, then you'll have to program something to adjust for your data.

Comment: Well `result.aDate` is returning an `IndexOutOfRangeException` with a value of `Monday,  01 - 01 - 0001 00:00:00` using `splits[2]` **and** `splits[0]`.

Comment: I made assumptions about the data that may not have been correct.  I've changed all the object properties of the class to string.  Everything should import fine now.  Look at the data as it comes in and make adjustments if necessary.  Also, use the debugger to look at the value of splits after its formed so that you can figure out where to put the data.

Comment: Debugger shows `char pipe` has a value of `124 '|'`. Maybe `Convert.ToChar("|")` is what's wrong?

Comment: Look at what's being returned in row["Running"].  You'll have to make adjustments based on what's being returned.  I can't see the data, so I don't know the answer.  I used Split because of how the two examples provided looked, but that may not be the best method.  However you split the data, just apply the data to the class and add the class to the List.  You can then access each value from the class to display.

Comment: I changed it to `splits = String.Format("{0}", show).Split(pipe)` and it successfully shows the first record but not the second one. How do I print the second one as well?

Comment: Split them in the for each loop.  If that doesn't work, post code so I can see what you've done.